# How to show list of installed calendars in settings screen of android

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, android-calendar, android-implicit-intent

I would like to display the list of installed calendars in android in the settings screen and select one among them. I saw this functionality in an android application [Cal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo.cal). 
Screenshot of the list of installed calendars in Cal app can be found [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/114342786@N08/11925694114/).

What I would like to know is "Is it possible to display the list of calendars using <preference> under res/XML"?

or

Do I have to select the list of calendars using PackageManager to find the list of all installed applications and displaying only the calendar applications?

I tried using <preference> using the below method

```
<Preference android:title="@string/pref_select_calendar" >
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.PICK"
        android:data="content://calendar/calendars" />
</Preference>
```

But I've got android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

```
{ act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://calendar/calenders }
```

What am I missing? or the approach I'm trying is not correct?
Any pointers will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to query the [CalendarProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) (available since API level 14)'s Calendars table for available calendars. The following snippet will show you how:

```
final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR
    };

    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    final Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    final List<CalendarInfo> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        /* do something with the cursor:
           Long id = cur.getLong(0);
           String name = cur.getString(1);
           int color = cur.getInt(2);
        */
    }
```

Since you're doing IO work (providers are basically SQLite databases), it's a solid idea to wrap everything into a separate (non-UI) thread; I'd go with [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki).

If you don't like playing with cursors, queries and boilerplate code, use the [CalendarWrapper](https://github.com/getinch/calendarwrapper) library. It takes care of mapping objects and database rows to and from, CRUD operations can be performed with object methods. For example in your case a single line would do the magic:

```
final List<Calendar> calendars = Calendar.getCalendarsForQuery(null, null, null, getContentResolver());
```

After you get a hold of the available calendars, just put them in a list and show it in a dialog, that's the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution  works exactly the way I wanted. But as you mentioned it is applicable only for API level 14 and above. Is there a similar solution which supports from GingerBread version or atleast from HoneyComb?

Comment: AFAIK there's no official, built-in way to do this (you mentioned Cal in your question - said app is also only for 4.0+ devices). However you can use the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) with a little extra coding.

Comment: I'm still searching for solution which is backward compatible till android 2.3. There are other apps in Play Store which are currently capable of doing this. eg. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.whatnapp.roomdisplay.v3